# servlet 3.0 getParts() method not found by netbeans, only by the debugger

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, file-upload, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to do a file upload for a project of me using Servlet 3.0 File Upload.
I have implemented what's been described here [at servletworld](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet3/multipartconfig-file-upload-example.html) but I have a very
strange issue:

Methods getParts() or getPart(part)  of HttpServletRequest cannot be found by the compiler!
Even stranger is following: when i debug the project with the netbeans debugger and add the following watch: "req.getParts()" it works fine, with correct results.

I later realized that any of the methods added in version3.0 of servlet cannot be found.
I am using Glassfish 3.1 server, which is meant to support servlet 3.0.

I would be very thankful to any idea or solution!

Comment: You probably have an older version of the servlet api jar in the classpath of your netbeans project.

Comment: @ JB Nizet, can you help me locating this jar ?

Comment: No, not with so few information. You really should be able to locate the libraries you're using in your IDE.

Comment: bet I am, but i can't find anything with name like "servlet something"

Comment: You can't, yet you have access to all the jar files (name and content). I don't have access to anything. How could I help? I don't have any crystal ball.

Comment: what's not clear is if the servlet jar is located in my project's folder (e.g. /lib, WEB-INF/lif etc..), in netbeans folder or in glassfish folder.

Comment: It must NOT be in WEB-INF/lib, since this jar is obviously provided by the servlet container.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?